# How to crete views (forms for user) in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I would like to write application in asp with login system.
I found this tutorial [tutorial](http://bitoftech.net/2015/01/21/asp-net-identity-2-with-asp-net-web-api-2-accounts-management/). I read it but I don't know how can I create forms (pages) for user, where he can write something. Could Somebody tell me how can I do it?

Comment: Follow an ASP.NET tutorial...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a basic form using [WebForms](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/creating-a-basic-web-forms-page) however I would preffer to use [MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started) because it give more control and flexibility in designing the user interface.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you found shows you how to use identity with a web api.  The web api will provide you a way to manipulate data.  The data should be consumed by either a webform or mvc application.  Here is a tutorial for how to make an MVC application. 
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started
This is a link to a video course that helped me learn MVC and Web API.
https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/developing-asp-net-mvc-4-web-applications-jump-start-8239?l=fwYCcoJy_2404984382